# What are the Golden Fields?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

What are the 'Golden Fields' beside Dagger Lake? Is it some sort of wheat-growing area or just wild growth? Is there any indication of who lives there?

The wikis say the river is infested with pirates and the area in general has no ruler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Golden Fields](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/File:Golden_Fields.png) are an area of land beside the river Rhoyne on the continent of Essos. Little is known about this area and it receives only one mention in the book series (in A Dance With Dragons). It isn't seen or mentioned in the TV series:

> “This is Ny Sar, where the Mother gathers in her Wild Daughter,
>   Noyne,” said Yandry, “but she will not reach her widest point until
>   she meets her other daughters. At Dagger Lake the Qhoyne comes rushing
>   in, the Darkling Daughter, full of gold and amber from the Axe and
>   pinecones from the Forest of Qohor. South of there the Mother meets
>   Lhorulu, the Smiling Daughter from the Golden Fields. Where they join
>   once stood Chroyane, the festival city, where the streets were made of
>   water and the houses made of gold. Then south and east again for long
>   leagues, until at last comes creeping in Selhoru, the Shy Daughter who
>   hides her course in reeds and writhes. There Mother Rhoyne waxes so
>   wide that a man upon a boat in the center of the stream cannot see a
>   shore to either side. You shall see, my little friend.”

Based on the fact that the land runs alongside the river, we can assume that it is fertile. There's no special mention of its occupants but given the lawless nature of the land outside the Flatlands (and the fact that the nearest city has been abandoned) I think we can reasonably assume that the land is either unoccupied, or at most occupied by smallholding farmers.

The gold colour likely comes from wild grass or wild wheat that has spread over from the more populous [Flatlands](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Flatlands) areas.

[image]